# initializing javascript with royal slider and masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, initialization, jquery-masonry

Sorry for the noob type question. There is a problem with my JS below. These elements below relate to RoyalSlider: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/ and Masonry.

When I place the masonry call at the bottom of the JS, it doesn't load. If I place it at the top it loads, but knocks out all the slider calls.

Even if I separate the scripts and place them in individual calls:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

...the problem persists (placing one call above the other, cancels the other one out).

This is my initialising script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

var rsi = $('#slideshow').royalSlider({
    startSlideId: 1,
    transitionSpeed: 300,
    slidesSpacing: 0,
    loop: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    arrowsNav: false,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: true,
    controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
    controlNavigation: 'tabs',
    imageAlignCenter:true,
    loopRewind: false,
    numImagesToPreload: 3,
    usePreloader: true,
    keyboardNavEnabled: false,
    sliderDrag: false,
    autoScaleSlider: true,  
    autoScaleSliderWidth: 980,     
    autoScaleSliderHeight: 653,
    allowCSS3: true,
    autoPlay: {
      enabled: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      delay: 4500,
      stopAtAction: false
    },
    thumbs: {
      firstMargin: false,
      spacing: 0,
      fitInViewport: true
    }

    }).data('royalSlider');
        $('#next').click(function() {
        rsi.next();
    });
        $('#prev').click(function() {
        rsi.prev();
    });

var slider = $('#wrp_hero');
    slider.after(slider.find('.rsNav'));


var rsi2 = $('#slider').royalSlider({
    transitionType: 'slide',
    arrowsNav: false,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
    controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
    controlNavigation: 'bullets',
    loop: false,
    loopRewind: false,
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    autoScaleSlider: false,
    sliderDrag: false,
    autoHeight: true
});

var $container = $('#portfolio');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.box'
    });
});

//end doc ready function    
});
```

This is at the bottom of my HTML doc above the body tag. s.js is my initialising script (as above):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/assets/j/l/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/assets/j/l/masonry.2.1.07.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/j/l/royalslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/j/p.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/j/s.js"></script>
<script>
  var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
  (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: any js errors in the console?

Comment: nope. Just `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'royalSlider'`error, because there are no sliders on the masonry page and vise versa.

Comment: have you declared the royalslider js plugin before your code?

Comment: Yep I have at the bottom of my html doc. I have updated my question with a basic html example.

Comment: @abhi - You were right. Didn't have the plugin code in the page. Thanks for your help.